# Set the default adb logcat output format

Tags: android, logcat, adb

I'm developing in a linux system (Ubuntu 12.04).
My favorite output format is `-v time`, but it is annoying to have to type `$ adb logcat -v time`every time I want to see a log message.

So, my question is: is there a way to configure adb to output time format as default?

I've looking over internet for an environmental variable to set the preferred format, but so far I've no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use an alias.

```
alias myalias='adb logcat -v time'
```

(use whatever you prefer instead of myalias. First letters, for instance `alvt`)

And put it in your `.bashrc`

Comment: Related to this question - users of the windows environment can create a similar alias using doskey like `doskey alvt=adb logcat -v time $*` as described here: http://superuser.com/questions/49170/create-an-alias-in-windows-xp

Comment: This doesn't work if you have to specify a -s or -d option.